# Possible to skip specific version of pod in cocoapods

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

I want to skip specific version of project in cocoapods, but I didn't find it how. Here's what cocoapods.org's guides pages says about versioning:

> Specifying pod versions
>
> When starting out with a project it is likely that you will want to
> use the latest version of a Pod. If this is the case, simply omit the
> version requirements. pod 'SSZipArchive' Later on in the project you
> may want to freeze to a specific version of a Pod, in which case you
> can specify that version number. pod 'Objection', '0.9' Besides no
> version, or a specific one, it is also possible to use logical
> operators:
>
> '> 0.1' Any version higher than 0.1
>
> '>= 0.1' Version 0.1 and any higher version
>
> '< 0.1' Any version lower than 0.1
>
> '<= 0.1' Version 0.1 and any lower version

In addition to the logic operators CocoaPods has an optimistic operator `~>`:

> '~> 0.1.2' Version 0.1.2 and the versions up to 0.2, not including 0.2 and higher
>
> '~> 0.1' Version 0.1 and the versions up to 1.0, not including 1.0 and higher
>
> '~> 0' Version 0 and higher, this is basically the same as not having it.

What I want is installing any version but not 6.6.0 for specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution and it's works like a charm :

```
pod 'FlurrySDK', '!= 6.6.0'
```

After saying `pod update`, here is the result :

```
Installing FlurrySDK 6.5.0 (was 6.6.0)
```

That means line above basically will skip the version `6.6.0` and install the latest version of the project. If there is `6.7.0` version of this project, it'll be installed in your project. But right now (*Aug 03, 2015*) latest version of this project is `6.6.0`. In this case latest version for this formula will be `6.5.0`.

I hope will help someone else.